# Windows Store App Visual Basic Set Foreground to RGB/aRGB value

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to change the foreground color of a textblock at runtime using Visual Basic in my Windows Store App. But, I don't know the proper way to do it. Please assist.

What I wrote was:

```
TextBlock1.Foreground = Windows.UI.Colors.Red
```

It says that "Value of type 'Windows.UI.Color' cannot be converted to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush'."

I've tried these all:

```
TextBlock1.Foreground = "Red"
TextBlock1.Foreground = "#FFC8C8C8"
TextBlock1.Foreground = &HFF0000FF&
TextBlock1.Foreground = &H0000FF&
```

I think I'm clearly missing the proper method. Any help is appreciated. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign it a `SolidColorBrush` not `Color`

```
Dim redBrush As New SolidColorBrush
redBrush.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Red
TextBlock1.Foreground = redBrush
```